# javascript split("\n\r") add comma on empty line

Tags: javascript, split, newline

I have below code which import file. I split it with split("\n\r") code but now every empty line has comma. How to fix it.. See code below and out put picture.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>


        <textarea id="textareaid" name="textareaid" class = "textdata" value="" rows="10" cols="100" placeholder="Enter Any Text!"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input id="filename"  class="btnsubmit"  type="file" accept="text/plain" onchange="PreviewText();"  />

<script type="text/javascript">

              function PreviewText() {
                var file = document.getElementById("filename").files[0];
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var array = e.target.result.split("\n\r");
                    alert (array);
                    document.getElementById("textareaid").value = array;
                    };
                    reader.readAsText(file);
        };

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: That's because `alert(array)` is essentially `alert(array.toString())`. Instead, `.join(…)` it back to a string with whatever separator you desire

Comment: `\n\r` - odd, I've never seen that line ending - it's usually `\n` or `\r\n` isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter all the lines which have only comma before displaying it in the textarea.

check the below code snippet. I have used `Array.filter` to check if the line has `,` or not.

```js
var array = [
  "Hello",
  ",",
  "Something",
  ",",
  "Great"
];

array = array.filter(function(line) {
  return line.length > 1 && line !== ",";
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this,  `Array.join(" ")` transform an array into a string and remove the separator, which in this case for arrays are **commas**

Check it out :

```
          function PreviewText() {
                var file = document.getElementById("filename").files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {

                var array = e.target.result.split("\n\r");
                document.getElementById("textareaid").value = array[0]
                document.getElementById("textareaid1").value = array[1]
                document.getElementById("textareaid2").value = array[2]
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);  // 
    };
```

========================================== // ==========================

If you want to do this dynamically, you can do like this:

```
array.forEach(function(article){
  list = document.createElement("ul");
  line = document.createElement("li");
  span = document.createElement("span");

  art = document.createTextNode(article) 

  span.appendChild(art);
  line.appendChild(span);
  list.appendChild(line);

  boxNode.appendChild(list)
})
```

**Example working (proof of concept)**
https://jsbin.com/fuyirajoni/edit?html,js,output

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: It does not work.. It give error..
Uncaught TypeError: e.target.result.join is not a function

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I have article which i want to convert into array. and then want you use 1st line in one textarea and rest article in the other textarea

Comment: Oh now I understood :) , just check the part two I am going to update right now :)

Comment: Thanks above code helped but not a good solution i have to add to many arrays to get values in 1 box.  This was array.slice(1) giving perfect result but adds comma on empty line